# Other efficient way to write multiple select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following queries:

```
select * from 
  ( select volume as vol1 from table1 where code='A1' and daytime='12-may-2012') a,
  ( select volume as vol2 from table2 where code='A2' and daytime='12-may-2012') b,
  ( select volume as vol3 from table3 where code='A3' and daytime='12-may-2012') c
```

result:

```
vol1 vol2 vol3
20   45
```

What would be other efficient way to write this query(in real case it could be up to 15 sub queries), assuming data not always exists in any of these tables for selected date? I think it could be join but not sure.

thanks,
S

Comment: Try using unions

Comment: If these are from different tables, then you are going to need some sort of query for each table.

Comment: can't use union, should be each column for each value.

Answer (score 0):

If the concern is that data might not exist, then cross join is not the right operator.  If any subquery returns zero rows, then you will get an empty result set.

Assuming at most one row is returned per query, just use subqueries in the `select`:

```
select (select volume from table1 where code = 'A1' and daytime = date '2012-05-12') as vol1,
       (select volume from table2 where code = 'A2' and daytime = date '2012-05-12') as vol2,
       (select volume from table3 where code = 'A3' and daytime = date '2012-05-12') as vol3
from dual;
```

If a value is missing, it will be `NULL`.  If a subquery returns more than one row, then you'll get an error.

I much prefer ANSI standard formats, which is why I use the `date` keyword.

I am highly suspicious of comparing a field called `datetime` to a date constant with no time component.  I would double check the logic on this.  Perhaps you intend `trunc(daytime) = date '2012-05-12'` or something similar.

I should also note that if performance is an issue, then you want an index on each table on `(code, daytime, volume)`.

Comment: Gordon, but this still is almost the same logic as original query, it was built few years ago, I thought it might be some diffrent way, for example not try to repeat daytime sincle it's the same for all 3 sub queries and etc.

Comment: @JoeGreen . . . This is not exactly the same logic.  Your original query will return no rows if any of the subqueries return no rows.

Comment: Gordon, let's say it won't be zero records and expecting result anyway what would be query with using join?

Comment: @JoeGreen . . . Your original query *does* use a join, albeit using a comma to mean `CROSS JOIN`.